# How do i customize this button in my login page?

Tags: html, css, web, button

```css
#button {
  background-color: #04AA6D;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px 32px;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 4px 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 50px;}
  
  .sign-up {
  border: 14px solid #00f535;
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 50px auto;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 50px;
  background-color: #b6f1c3;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
</section>
<form action="/anth/">
  <div class="sign-up">
    <div id="name">
  <h3>Sign up</h3>
</div>
  <div id="username">
  <label for="username">Username</label>
  <input type="email" name="username" placeholder="Youe name" id="username" required pattern="[a-zA-Z]+">
</div>
<div id="password">
  <label for="usr-pass">Password</label>
  <input type="password" name="pass" id="usr-pass" placeholder="Password" required pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9]+">
</div>
<div id="button">
  <input type="submit" value="send">
</div>
</div>
  <section class="useless">
  <br><br><br>
  <label for="age">Your age</label>
  <input type="number" name="num" step="1" id="age" placeholder="1-100" required min="1" max="100">
  <br>
  <input type="submit" value="send">
  <br><br>
  <label for="vol">volume</label>
  <input type="range" name="volume" id="vol" min="0" max="100" step="5">
  <div>
<br>
</section>
```

[The button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KbVt0.png)Iam a beginner at html and css and im trying to create a login page as my first project but this button for some reasons doesnt seems to be going along with what i want. If someone could help me just some minor adjustments not anything to fancy such as annimations and stuff , just to match with what ive already did.

Ive tried using some stuff i found online but it just seems to put a border around it nothing else.

Comment: And what do you want to achieve? Maybe post an image how the button should look like, describe color, border, font etc, it should have… and also add the code you already have.

Comment: You probably want to put the `button` id in the submit button tag. Like this: https://codepen.io/kikosoft/pen/mdGpYgx

Comment: @KIKOSoftware thank you i've got it now, how do i mark my question as solved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this if you like

```css
/* CSS for desktop screens */

/* main container */
.sign-up {
  max-width: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

/* input fields */
input[type="email"],
input[type="password"],
input[type="number"],
input[type="range"] {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px 0;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

/* submit button */
input[type="submit"] {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px 0;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #008CBA;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
}

/* CSS for mobile screens */

@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  /* main container */
  .sign-up {
    max-width: none;
    padding: 10px;
  }

  /* input fields */
  input[type="email"],
  input[type="password"],
  input[type="number"],
  input[type="range"] {
    margin: 5px 0;
  }

  /* submit button */
  input[type="submit"] {
    margin: 5px 0;
  }
}
```

```html
</section>
<form action="/anth/">
  <div class="sign-up">
    <div id="name">
  <h3>Sign up</h3>
</div>
  <div id="username">
  <label for="username">Username</label>
  <input type="email" name="username" placeholder="Youe name" id="username" required pattern="[a-zA-Z]+">
</div>
<div id="password">
  <label for="usr-pass">Password</label>
  <input type="password" name="pass" id="usr-pass" placeholder="Password" required pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9]+">
</div>
<div id="button">
  <input type="submit" value="send">
</div>
</div>
  <section class="useless">
  <br><br><br>
  <label for="age">Your age</label>
  <input type="number" name="num" step="1" id="age" placeholder="1-100" required min="1" max="100">
  <br>
  <input type="submit" value="send">
  <br><br>
  <label for="vol">volume</label>
  <input type="range" name="volume" id="vol" min="0" max="100" step="5">
  <div>
<br>
</section>
```

Comment: Thank you  , one more question if you dont mind , how do i customize the input filed, like which line changes how the field looks like

Comment: check this 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms/Advanced_form_styling

Answer (score 0):

u need to use the tag button instead of the div and change the colors and what u want also use the :hover and transition to animate ur button . to develop ur level u need to work on real projects just go to figma community and choose a UI design and try to do it with HTML CSS. good luck
check this out :

```css
button {
  background-color: lightcoral;
  padding: 8px 30px;
  margin-top: 25px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

button:hover{
  background-color: lightgray;
}

  
  .sign-up {
  border: 14px solid #00f535;
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 50px auto;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 50px;
  background-color: #b6f1c3;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
</section>
<form action="/anth/">
  <div class="sign-up">
    <div id="name">
  <h3>Sign up</h3>
</div>
  <div id="username">
  <label for="username">Username</label>
  <input type="email" name="username" placeholder="Youe name" id="username" required pattern="[a-zA-Z]+">
</div>
<div id="password">
  <label for="usr-pass">Password</label>
  <input type="password" name="pass" id="usr-pass" placeholder="Password" required pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9]+">
</div>
<button>send</button>
</div>
  <section class="useless">
  <br><br><br>
  <label for="age">Your age</label>
  <input type="number" name="num" step="1" id="age" placeholder="1-100" required min="1" max="100">
  <br>
  <input type="submit" value="send">
  <br><br>
  <label for="vol">volume</label>
  <input type="range" name="volume" id="vol" min="0" max="100" step="5">
  <div>
<br>
</section>
```

Comment: Much appriciate it , iam trying to get better day by day on working in my project